# Additional Private Network

Tags: nginx, linux-networking

I have set up a Ubuntu 18.0.4 VPS. I have taken a private network package and connected the VPS. This to use for a load balancer and several servers internal communication. I still need to manually add private network details to `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`. Tough for me as I am still pretty green and the hosters documentation is behind and replies not always complete. Been at it for 3-4 days now and talking to them just as long.

Under that file `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` I initially have the following auto generated which works fine:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

Last setup which blocked ssh access or pinging was

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      addresses:
      - xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/24
      - xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx:xxx:xx:xxx:xxxx/64
    ens7:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
      - 10.0.0.2/8
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
```

I did a `sudo netplan apply --debug` and no issues. But no pining nor ssh possible though.

For the addresses I first just added the ipv4 address and ipv6 address. Then as I got blocked access I logged in using the VPS console and I tried the ip ranges for both. Still no joy - no ping/ssh possible. Prefixes seem necessary though so used /24 and 64 for both options and I think I should keep them.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the configuration of ens3, if it already works?

Comment: I was told it needs to have an ip address as well to work with the second network added. No idea why as the auto generated stuff has DHCP already and was working. I could leave it be and did before. But there were still issues then as well. So even when I leave it as be it still seems to be needing work..